# Problems adding map inside Childview of ExpandableListview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, supportmapfragment

I add `Map` using `Fragment` inside ChildView of `ExpandableListview`.

Map is not displayed when I expand all childviews of `ExpandableListView`. I scroll to the end of `ExpandableListView` and scroll back up, now the map is displayed.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You can use MapView inside expandable listview.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback callback) you can set up listener for when GoogleMap is ready

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback { 
... 
}
```

---

```
@Override 
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
        .title("Marker"));
}
```